# Cocoa app Bash Script Variables

Tags: cocoa, bash, variables, reference

I would like to reference a variable that I have in a bash script "value" as well as "max." As of now, I have a text interface in which after given commands, the terminal window displays something similar to

> ==========================================================================> 100%

for a progress bar. The variable is referenced throughout the script, and I would like to call that variable in my cocoa app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but it sounds like you want to use environment variables.  In bash, you need to use the [`export` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) to mark a variable to be exported to child processes.  Then, in your Cocoa app, you can use [`getenv(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/getenv.3.html) function to retrieve the environment variable value.  For example:

```
# In your bash script
value=foo
max=bar
export value max

// Now in your Cocoa application:
char *value;
if((value = getenv("value")))
{
    // Use value
}
// else value is not in the environment
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'm sorry that my question wasn't clear! But, I think you have answered it just fine. What I was trying to ask was a way to reference variables, which I believe you have answered just fine! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Wait, now I am confused in implementing the bash functionality with the cocoa app. This is what I am currently doing.

First, I have my source code imported into the cocoa app. 
Second, I make sure my source code imported has the export value max.
Third, I attempt to implement the bash script into the app.

Now I am confused on this part, how would I implement this? Would I simply use the variables as you have suggested? Does the bash script need to be run somewhere? How would I run the bash script in the background without a terminal window?

Thanks again!